# SQL Server - Get highest values when previous date not blank

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains information for player's steps taken for any given day, I want to get the 3 highest totals from the database, when the day before the day of the high total has a value added to it for that player. Since some players are not logging everyday, but rather lumping multiple days into one update.

Data Structure:

```
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
| id | player_id | steps | date       | submitted               |
|----|-----------|-------|------------|-------------------------|
| 1  | 16        | 5718  | 2012-09-06 | 2012-09-10 08:31:35.000 |
| 2  | 16        | 9837  | 2012-09-07 | 2012-09-10 08:31:17.000 |
| 3  | 16        | 10432 | 2012-09-09 | 2012-09-10 08:30:54.000 |
| 4  | 30        | 3973  | 2012-09-07 | 2012-09-10 09:34:42.000 |
| 5  | 30        | 7104  | 2012-09-08 | 2012-09-10 09:35:05.000 |
| 6  | 30        | 10916 | 2012-09-09 | 2012-09-10 09:35:29.000 |
| 7  | 9         | 6437  | 2012-09-07 | 2012-09-10 09:39:15.000 |
| 8  | 9         | 9032  | 2012-09-08 | 2012-09-10 09:40:02.000 |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
```

So what I want to return are the rows:

```
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
| 6  | 30        | 10916 | 2012-09-09 | 2012-09-10 09:35:29.000 |
| 2  | 16        | 9837  | 2012-09-07 | 2012-09-10 08:31:17.000 |
| 8  | 9         | 9032  | 2012-09-08 | 2012-09-10 09:40:02.000 |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
```

My query is currently:

```
SELECT TOP 3 p.name,
             player_id,
             steps,
             date
FROM   steppers_step_log
       JOIN steppers_players P
         ON player_id = P.id
ORDER  BY steps DESC
```

Which does not take into account whether there is an entry for the date prior on the top 3 from steps, which with my query in its current form will return 10432, 10916, and 9837 as the top steps.

I am having trouble working out how to do the WHERE command to make sure that the previous day has an entry for that player_id and would appreciate any help in getting it working.

Comment: Is the combination (player_id, date) unique?

Comment: Laurence, not explicitly, but yes it is.

Comment: If you can guarantee it, you can solve it just by doing from steppers_step_log l1 inner join steppers_step_log l2 on l1.player_id = l2.player_id and l1.date = l2.date - 1. It's probably no more efficient than the exists form of the query, though. And that works either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT TOP 3 p.name,
             player_id,
             steps,
             date
FROM   steppers_step_log
       JOIN steppers_players P
         ON player_id = P.id
WHERE EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM steppers_step_log ssp
   WHERE ssp.player_id = P.id
   AND date = DATEADD(day, -1, steppers_step_log.date)
)
ORDER  BY steps DESC
```

[DATEADD (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

Comment: Works like a charm. Just couldn't wrap my head around the where clause.

Comment: It just means that you only want records([`EXISTS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) returns a boolean) where the player is the same as in the main query and the date is the day before(`DATEADD(day, -1, steppers_step_log.date)`). Ignore the `1` in the sub-query, you could even select `null` or `*`, the result would be the same. The [`EXISTS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) is `true` when at least one record is returnd from the sub-query.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add a `WHERE` clause using an `EXISTS` condition...

```
SELECT TOP 3
  p.name,
  player_id,
  steps,
  date
FROM
  steppers_step_log    AS log
INNER JOIN
  steppers_players     AS players
     ON log.player_id = players.id
WHERE
  EXISTS (
    SELECT *
      FROM steppers_step_log
     WHERE player_id = players.id
       AND date      = log.date - 1
  )
ORDER BY
  log.steps DESC
```

This *can* however, return the same player more than once; if they have more than one entry in the top 3.  Is that what you want?

Comment: That would be an acceptable scenario, your query returned the proper results. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to solve this.  Others will probably do the solution with a join/exists type query.  I like an alternative approach that uses ranking functions to get the appropriate row.

What you are looking for are sequences of uploads, and then you don't want the first.  You can define a sequence by enumerating the rows for a player.  Then, for each sequence the difference between the date and the sequence is a constant.  Then, additional rankings get what you want.

To define the sequences:

```
select stl.*,
       row_number() over (partition by player_id, groupid order by date) as seqnum
from (select stl.*,
             datediff(day, date,
                      row_number() over (partition by player_id order by date) as groupid
      from steppers_step_log stl
     ) stl
```

Now, you can get the "qualifying" rows by using:

```
where seqnum > 1
```

To get the three highest values for each player, you would can do:

```
with stl as (<above query>)
select *
from (select stl.*,
             row_number() over (partition by player_id order by steps desc) as scorenum
      from stl
      where seqnum > 1
     ) stl
where scorenum <= 3
```